# Gitlab CI - npm install command terminates current step

Tags: npm-install, gitlab-ci

Using Gitlab (Community Version 8.13) CI I want to be able to install all jspm dependencies before publishing site.

I've package.json which defines jspm as dev dependency:

```
{
  "jspm": {
    "directories": {
      "baseURL": ...
    },
    "dependencies": {
      ...
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        ...
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jspm": "^0.16.48"
  }
}
```

Now in my .gitlab-ci.yml file I've defined a step:

```
jspm:
  stage: jspm
  script:
  - echo "npm install"
  - 'npm install'
  - echo "Trigger jspm install"
  - ./node_modules/.bin/jspm install
```

The problem which I have is that after `npm install` next script command is not being triggered.
Here you could see log from this step. Looks like npm is able to install all packages but then even next `echo` command is not being triggered. (To simplify the log I've removed all installed packages listed by npm).

```
"npm install"
$ npm install
C:\Multi-Runner\builds\c144e1e9\0\{path to website}
`-- jspm@0.16.48 
 {lots of dependend packages listed here} 

Build succeeded
```

Do you have any suggestions ? I could provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 0):

My gitlab runner was installed on Windows machine.
According to: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2938

I've changed the step:

```
jspm:
 stage: jspm
 script:
 - echo "npm install"
 - call npm install
 - echo "Trigger jspm install"
 - call ./node_modules/.bin/jspm install
```

And it works fine now.